# Why is my sound in Mumble bad?

Tags: windows-7, audio, mumble

Sound generated by Mumble (i.e. other users and the test voice in the audio wizard) sounds  "scratchy".
I know that it's only Mumble because playing music via Media Player works just fine, so my general configuration seems to be fine.

I'm using Mumble on Win7. Before that I used it on WinXP with identical Hardware; everything was fine.
What could be the problem?

Comment: is one of the input/output levels set too high?

Comment: Sorry, where can I check that? I skipped Vista so I'm not that familiar with Win7 yet...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I [found a solution](http://sourceforge.net/forum/forum.php?thread_id=3370688&forum_id=492607): Running it in Win XP compatibility mode works fine.

Answer (score 0):

right click on the speaker tray icon > Recording devices > double click **Microphone** > open the tab **Levels**

reduce the volume and try again.

Comment: Hm, without being able to try that right now: It's not my voice that's scratchy. It is the sound that Mumble produces when other users speak.